# NSDocument to hold a complete folder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, directory, nsdocument

I ask sorry if this argument has already been covered, but after some research i found nothing precise.

I need to make a document based application, where the document is actually not a single file but a structured collection of files, in a directory. The windows will show a pdf contained in the folder, with a specific filename, and enrich it with informations from the other files in the folder. 
I cannot use pdf annotations to achieve this, i really need to keep the files separated from the pdf.

What's the best approach to achieve this? All the sample code i found use a single file..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `NSFileWrapper` as a package directory in document-based applications.

In your application Info.plist file, state that your document type is a package or bundle (key `LSTypeIsPackage` with value `YES`).

In your `NSDocument` subclass, implement the following methods for reading and writing. In this example, I’m assuming the corresponding model instance variables are `pdfData` and `signatureBitmapData`, which are stored in the package directory under MainDocument.pdf and SignatureBitmap.png, respectively.

```
- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)dirWrapper
                     ofType:(NSString *)typeName
                      error:(NSError **)outError
{

    NSFileWrapper *wrapper;
    NSData *data;

    wrapper = [[dirWrapper fileWrappers] objectForKey:@"MainDocument.pdf"];
    data = [wrapper regularFileContents];
    self.pdfData = data;

    wrapper = [[dirWrapper fileWrappers] objectForKey:@"SignatureBitmap.png"];
    data = [wrapper regularFileContents];
    self.signatureBitmapData = data;

    …

    return YES;
}

- (NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName
                               error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSFileWrapper *dirWrapper = [[[NSFileWrapper alloc]
        initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil] autorelease];

    [dirWrapper addRegularFileWithContents:self.pdfData
        preferredFilename:@"MainDocument.pdf"];

    [dirWrapper addRegularFileWithContents:self.signatureBitmapData
        preferredFilename:@"SignatureBitmap.png"];

    …

    return dirWrapper;
}
```

From the user perspective, the package directory shows up in Finder as if it were a single file, much like Xcode .xcodeproj directories or application bundles.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i'll try this immediatly.

Comment: @hariseldon78 Cheers. Just one remark: I haven’t included error checking and reporting in my example, but you should do that in your production code.

Comment: Would it be possible to open MainDocument.pdf without specifying LSTypeIsPackage and just save the document together with the image file using the NSFileWrapper API?