# Xcode - Document Based Application (Document Bundle)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdocument

I'm trying to find a somewhat more comprehensive writeup, or an example to refer to regarding a *Document Based Application* which saves it's contents to a document bundle rather than a single file.

A good example of what I mean by a document bundle is how Pages saves it's documents i.e.

```
Document Name.myextension\
                          directory1\
                                     somefile.ext
                                     somefile2.ext
                          directory2\
                          directory3\
                          file1.png
                          file2.png
```

As we know apples documentation, although extensive, can, at the best of times be somewhat daunting to work with :-/

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Ade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following Stack Overflow question:

[NSDocument to hold a complete folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665560/nsdocument-to-hold-a-complete-folder)

If the answer to that question isn't detailed enough, you can read the following article on file packages:

[Working with Cocoa File Packages](http://meandmark.com/blog/2010/10/working-with-cocoa-file-packages/)

Regarding Apple's documentation, the relevant classes to look at are NSFileWrapper, NSData, and NSDocument.

Comment: Thanks... After some ploughing and wading through the myriads of apple docs, I managed to get the swing of things. None the less, those two links you shares were priceless gems of help!